# Setting up a XNAT server with a NAS

Tags: docker, nas, mri, xnat

I'm setting up an XNAT server using their container service. But I want to archive my files in a separated server/NAS.

Has anyone done this before? Any tutorial on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my search:

"The easiest way to do this would be to mount the location on your NAS where you want the data to be archived to the location of the archive folder on your XNAT server. You can probably configure your containers to run so that they write data directly to the NAS storage rather than to your XNAT server. That would reduce network traffic, since writing to the XNAT server directly would then require sending the data across the network connection to the NAS. That said, I have no idea how to do that part and will defer to Flavin et al as far as configuring how your containers interact with the archive space."